# run-time error '1004' defining variables and objects error

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
sub test()
list1 = Sheets(1).Range("a2", Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
list2 = Sheets(2).Range("a2", Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

MsgBox list1
MsgBox list2
end sub
```

when I have naviagated away from the sheet I have issues, I have created a solution:

```
Sub tester()

Dim list1 As Range

With ActiveWorkbook

Set list1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2")
Set list1 = Range(list1, list1.End(xlDown))
MsgBox list1.Rows.Count

End With
End Sub
```

the above is an example for list1, but this seems like overkills. am i doing something wrong, do i have some settings, in references not activated, or something? i have excel2013 so have microsoft office object library 15?? thanks

Comment: Can you please expand on "i have issues"?

Answer (score 1):

> when I have naviagated away from the sheet I have issues

Yes. You are not fully qualifying the objects

Try this (UNTESTED)

```
Sub test()
    list1 = Sheets(1).Range("a2", Sheets(1).Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    list2 = Sheets(2).Range("a2", Sheets(1).Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    MsgBox list1
    MsgBox list2
End Sub
```

Having said that, my preferred way of working is to declare the objects and then work with them

So the above code can be written as (UNTESTED)

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim list1 As Long, List2 As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)

    list1 = ws1.Range("A2", ws1.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    List2 = ws2.Range("a2", ws2.Range("a2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    MsgBox list1
    MsgBox List2
End Sub
```

Comment: looks good, and works, but as a general question? the method i posted before can that work in any circumstance/setting?

Comment: You are using `Activeworkbook` So if you navigate to some other workbook then you will not get desired results :) Also in `Set list1 = Range(list1, list1.End(xlDown))`, the range is not qualified completely again. So in short.. No. You code can fail :)